# Is it normal after editing an item in one display for Views to always go back to the first display

Tags: views

Drupal7 & Views 7.x-3.3 My site installation of Views has several working Views. There is a strange behavior in the GUI and its very annoying. After editing an item, Views always goes back to the first display!?!

For example, the included example view, "Front page (Content)", has two displays, Page & Feed. To recreate this annoyance edit the Front Page View, then:

1. Select the display Feed;
2. Edit any item, such as: Display name: / Page /
3. Make changes, then save;

Page refresh returns to Front Page's View edit page, and in my installation the Feed display is no longer selected. Now the Page display is selected. This happens every time for all Views. After editing an item in one display, the page refreshes back to the first display (at left). This was not the case with Views 2 and Drupal 6. Its the equivalent of changing tabs after saving something.

Comment: I'm not showing this behavior with 3.3 or 7.x-3.x-dev

Comment: Hmm. er...yay! At least views isn't broken. Thanks for your post...

Comment: I had this problem with views in D6, but there in not like this problem in D7

Comment: What's really strange is I've uninstalled and reinstalled the views module with several times troubleshooting another problem. How could this problem persist each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its just a bug of `views/settings/advanced` and the setting "Disable JavaScript with Views".

At the time of asking this question, I was troubleshooting errors in the Views plugin [Draggableviews](http://drupal.org/project/draggableviews) that were appearing in the Views UI.

Related to this is another bug where its impossible to *remove* a `Filter Criteria` value without JavaScript enabled.